# Is it possible to run an ember-cli app without an HTTP server?

Tags: ember.js, build

I've been working on an ember app and I'm trying to create a production build so my manager can look at it, I ran

> ember build --environment=production

but it when I open the index.html file I get a 404 error for my app.css and app.js files, this only happens when the files are not served by an HTTP server. Is it possible to run the files locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, when using the file URI scheme `file://path/to/your/app` the relative paths used in `index.html` won't be resolved properly. It will also break the router even if you correct the paths manually.

Comment: I guess you could upload those files somewhere and send him a link? Say, a dropbox public folder, not sure.